# C# - Executing CMD.exe with Arguments containing %VS110COMNTOOLS%

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying to execute the below mentioned command on cmd.exe from C#. I have tried the the below mentioned methods but none of them seem to work. They all are able to open CMD but nothing happens after that. Also if I use simple arguments like - "/C start winword" it works with Method 3 only.

Also I have tried adding /C and /K to the argumentstring but they don't seem to work as well.

```
        string argumentString = "\"%VS110COMNTOOLS%/../IDE/devenv.exe\" /diff " + "\"" + txt_File1.Text + "\" \"" + txt_file2.Text + "\"";
        //string argumentString = "start winword";

        // Method 1 
        System.Diagnostics.Process ExecuteCommand = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

        startInfo.Arguments = argumentString;
        ExecuteCommand.StartInfo = startInfo;
        ExecuteCommand.Start();

        //Method 2
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"cmd.exe", argumentString);

        // Method 3
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", argumentString);
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Why aren't you starting the mentioned executables directly?
I mean  why aren't you doing something like this: startInfo.FileName = "winword.exe"?

Comment: I actually just trying to see if word opens using this approach. I actually want to the argument - "\"%VS110COMNTOOLS%/../IDE/devenv.exe\" /diff " + "\"" + txt_File1.Text + "\" \"" + txt_file2.Text + "\"";

Answer (score 0):

Adding /k to arguments of cmd.exe does the work.

Check out the code:

```
using System;

namespace ProcessRun
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var argumentString = "\"%VS120COMNTOOLS%/../IDE/devenv.exe\" /diff " + "\"" + txt_File1 + "\" \"" + txt_file2 + "\"";
            string argumentString = "start winword";

            // Method 1 
            Method1(argumentString);

            //Method 2
            Method2(argumentString);

            // Method 3
            Method3(argumentString);
        }

        private static void Method3(string argumentString)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k " + argumentString);
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
            string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private static void Method2(string argumentString)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"cmd.exe", "/k " + argumentString);
        }

        private static void Method1(string argumentString)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process ExecuteCommand = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

            startInfo.Arguments = "/k " + argumentString;
            ExecuteCommand.StartInfo = startInfo;
            ExecuteCommand.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vitaliy, but I actually want to use the argument -                           'var argumentString = "\"%VS120COMNTOOLS%/../IDE/devenv.exe\" /diff " + "\"" + txt_File1 + "\" \"" + txt_file2 + "\""; ' I was using the winword just to test